# React: should I use routing or conditionally render a sequence of views?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, page-refresh, redux-persist, reach-router

I've come across this situation multiple times in a web app I'm building, and I'm looking for a best practice to implement and refactor according to.

As a part of onboarding, the user is going to create a pin, click/tap a button to save it to state and move to a new view (or route), re-enter the pin, and click/tap a button to confirm and submit it, sending it off to the backend.

I'm trying determine the best way to build this out to handle unintentional refreshes or refreshes that occur mid-story before the info is sent to the server.

I see a few ways to handle/build this:

1. I could build this using routing (i.e. `foo.com/account/pin/create` and then `foo.com/account/pin/confirm`) and pass the pin through props provided by the router. If the user refreshes at `/pin/confirm` though, the pin passed from `/pin/create` gets lost though. I could check for the prop and redirect them back to `/pin/create` and display a message why.
2. I could build this without routing, with a class container that has a `state.view` prop. in the render, I'd run a switch to determine which UI component(s) are displayed based on `state.view`. Example:

```
class foo extends Component {
  state = {
    view: 'view1',
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    // send data off
  };

  cycleView = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      switch (prevState.view) {
        case 'view1':
          return { view: 'view2' };
        case 'view2':
          return { view: 'view3' };
        case 'view3':
          this.handleSubmit();
          navigate('/dash');
          break;
        default:
          return { view: 'notice' };
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { view } = this.state;

    const mainComponent = () => {
      switch (view) {
        case 'view1':
          return <View1 />;
        case 'view2':
          return <View2 />;
        case 'view3':
          return <View3 />;
      }
    };

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <ProgressIndicator currentStep={2} numberOfSteps={4} />

        {mainComponent()}

        <Nextbutton
          ctaText="Next"
          onClick={
            view === 'view1' || view === 'view2'
              ? this.cycleView
              : this.handleSubmit
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

3. I could use Redux-Persist to store it in local storage, but putting a private PIN in the browser's local storage feels icky. (Is this as insecure I as I've been led to believe?) Further, I tend to prefer composing things and avoid putting things in Redux that aren't really global in nature.

So the question is which of these options is best? Or is there a better one I haven't listed?

Of note: I'm using @reach/router.

Edited to add code snippet.

Comment: I gad the same question a few days a go and forgot to post it! It would even be better if you post how different they are as a code

Comment: If you want to store data post-refresh you need to store it locally anyway, so your option 3 does not sound so bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with option 2 in most cases. From a user's perspective they are still doing 1 thing. If I refreshed at the confirm step, I would expect to start over with a new pin. Imagine I started the process and got distracted and came back to the form having forgotten what I set originally. That is a legitimate case where I would refresh on purpose, and would actively want the form to be reset. In other cases, it's a minor inconvenience to re-enter a pin.

There are ways you could clean this model up too. For instance you could make the next button part of the switch statement or the child components and give them unique actions so you wouldn't need a switch statement in your event handler. Or, if this is a really common pattern, create an abstract component that handles the switching for you.

If you had something like a shopping cart where each step you saved a users choices to an api or local storage, then option 1 or 3 would make more sense.